# How can I convert a Dart model class to a list without a builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

In a Flutter app I have an rxDart bloc which takes a JSON string from an API server and converts is to a list of a class (Sale).

In addition to displaying the data on a ListView widget, I want to print the data using the package `pdf: 1.3.23`.

The pdf package has a builder but won't take a ListView so I need to convert my list of Sales to List> so I can pass it to Table.fromTextArray.

Or, more generally, how do I create a pdf from a parsed API response? Or, how can I create a pdf from data? Printing the data from a flutter screen has to be the second most common requirement after displaying the data but I can find no clues in srearches as to how to go about that.

I get this message when I try to pass my SalesResponse object to Table.fromTextArray.

> The argument type 'SalesResponse' can't be assigned to the parameter
>   type List< List< String>>.

Here is my code so far:

Sale model:

```
class Sale {
  int _id;
  int _billId;
  String _item;
  int _qty;
  double _price;

  Sale(sale) {
    _id = sale['id'];
    _billId = sale['bill_id'];
    _item = sale['item'];
    _qty = sale['qty'];
    _price = (sale['price'] as num).toDouble();
  }

  int get id => _id;
  int get billId => _billId;
  String get item => _item;
  int get qty => _qty;
  double get price => _price;
}
```

Here is my sales response model

```
import 'package:exactpos_mobile/model/sale.dart';

class SalesResponse {
  List<Sale> _sales = [];
  String error;

  SalesResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    print(parsedJson);
    List<Sale> temp = [];
    if (parsedJson['sales'] != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < parsedJson['sales'].length; i++) {
        Sale _sale = Sale(parsedJson['sales'][i]);
        temp.add(_sale);
      }
      _sales = temp;    
    }
  }

  SalesResponse.withError(String errorValue)
      : _sales = List(),
        error = errorValue;

  List<Sale> get sales => _sales;
}
```

Sales repository

```
class SaleRepository{
  ApiProvider _apiProvider = ApiProvider();

  Future<SalesResponse> getSales(int billId){
    return _apiProvider.getSales(billId);
  }
}
```

Sales Bloc

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class SalesBloc {
  final SaleRepository _repository = SaleRepository();
  final PublishSubject<SalesResponse> _subject = PublishSubject<SalesResponse>();
  getSales(int billId) async {
    SalesResponse response = await _repository.getSales(billId); 
    _subject.sink.add(response);
  }
  void dispose() async{
    await _subject.drain();
    _subject.close();
  }
  PublishSubject<SalesResponse> get subject => _subject;
}
final salesBloc = SalesBloc();
```

Here is my widget screen

```
SalesResponse salesList;

class SalesScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  static const routeName = '/sales';

  final Bill bill;
  final Tbl table;

  SalesScreen({    
    Key key,
    @required this.table,
    @required this.bill
   }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => SalesScreenState();      
}

class SalesScreenState extends State<SalesScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    salesBloc.getSales(widget.bill.id);

    salesList = salesBloc.getSales(widget.bill.id); 

      print('hello');
      print(salesList.sales);
      print('hello');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    salesBloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
              drawer: AppDrawer(),
              appBar: AppBar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,

                        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                        centerTitle : true,
                        title: Text(widget.bill.billNumber.toString(), 
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                                    ),
                        leading: IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                                  onPressed:() =>
                        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                             builder: (context) =>
                               BillsScreen(table: widget.table)), (Route<dynamic> route) => false)
                        )
              ),
              body: SafeArea(
                child: Container(
                       child: 
                          StreamBuilder<SalesResponse>(
                              stream: salesBloc.subject.stream,          
                              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<SalesResponse> snapshot) {
                                     if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                        if (snapshot.data.error != null && snapshot.data.error.length > 0) {
                                           return _buildErrorWidget(snapshot.data.error);
                                        }
                                        return _buildSalesListWidget(snapshot.data);
                                     } 
                              },
                          )
              ),
        ),

              floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
                 floatingActionButton: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: <Widget>[

                                 FloatingActionButton(
                                    heroTag: 1,
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                                    onPressed: () {
                                        Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout:(format)=> 
                                           buildReceipt(widget.table, 
                                                        widget.bill, 
                                                        salesList));
                                    },
                                    child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.print),
                                 ),
                              ],
                    ),
                )

    );

  }

  Widget _buildSalesListWidget(SalesResponse data) {

          return ListView.builder(            
                     itemCount: data.sales.length,
                     itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                         return ListTile(                                             
                                  title: Text(                                            
                                              data.sales[index].item,                                          
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,        
                                                         fontSize: 20,
                                              ),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Text('qty' + ' ' + data.sales[index].qty.toString() + ', ' + 'price' + ' ' + data.sales[index].price.toStringAsFixed(2)),
                                  leading: Icon(
                                                FontAwesomeIcons.beer,
                                                color: Colors.blue[500],
                                  ),           
                                  onTap: () {},
                         );
                     },
        );
  }
 }
```

Finally, my pdf code

```
Future<List<int>> buildReceipt(Tbl table, Bill bill,  SalesResponse salesList)  async {

  const PdfPageFormat format = PdfPageFormat(160, 900);

  final Document pdf = Document();

    pdf.addPage(MultiPage(

      pageFormat: format, //  PdfPageFormat.a4.copyWith(marginBottom: 1.5 * PdfPageFormat.cm),

      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

      header: (Context context) {

        if (context.pageNumber == 1) {
          return null;
        }

        return Container(

            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,

            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0 * PdfPageFormat.mm),

            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0 * PdfPageFormat.mm),

            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border:
                    BoxBorder(bottom: true, width: 0.5, color: PdfColors.grey)),

            child: Text('Exact POS',
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .defaultTextStyle
                    .copyWith(color: PdfColors.grey)));
      },
      footer: (Context context) {
        return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
            child: Text('Page ${context.pageNumber} of ${context.pagesCount}',
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .defaultTextStyle
                    .copyWith(color: PdfColors.grey)));
      },
      build: (Context context) => <Widget>[
            Header(
                level: 0,
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Exact POS', textScaleFactor: 2),
                      PdfLogo()
                    ]
                )
            ),

            Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4)),

            Paragraph(text: table.number),

            Table.fromTextArray(context: context, data: salesList  ),
      ]
    )
  );
  return pdf.save();
}
```

Comment: There's no way to do such a thing automatically in Dart as of today. You either have to list all of your properties yourself or make some code generator. It would be possible to do using reflections, but dart:mirrors library isn't available with flutter framework.

Comment: How would I go about "listing the properties"?

Comment: Something like this: `List<String> get stringProps => [_id, _billId, _item, _qty, _price].map((p) => p.toString()).toList();`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Table.fromTextArray` expects a `List<List<String>>` as `data` and you are passing a `SalesResponse`.

Here is a quick example of how you could do it:

```
Table.fromTextArray(context: context, data: <List<String>>[
  <String>['Id', 'Bill Id', 'Item', 'Qty', 'Price'],
  ...salesList.sales.map((s) =>
  ['${s.id}', '${s.billId}', '${s.item}', '${s.qty}', '${s.price}']),
])
```

---

Or create a getter in `Sale` to get the list, like this:

```
List<String> get stringList => ['$id', '$billId', '$item', '$qty', '$price'];
```

Then use it like this:

```
Table.fromTextArray(context: context, data: <List<String>>[
  <String>['Id', 'Bill Id', 'Item', 'Qty', 'Price'],
  ...salesList.sales.map((sale) => sale.stringList),
])
```

---

Or directly create a getter in `SalesResponse` to get the list of list, like this:

```
List<List<String>> get salesStringList =>
    <List<String>>[
      <String>['Id', 'Bill Id', 'Item', 'Qty', 'Price'],
      ...sales.map((sale) => sale.stringList),
    ];
```

Then use it like this:

```
Table.fromTextArray(context: context, data: salesList.salesStringList)
```